# Weird exception with OLEDB Parameter Insert

Tags: c#, ms-access-2007, oledb, jet, oledbcommand

Getting a strange error when trying to insert data into an Access database using parameters. the line where I am getting a problem is :-

```
                thisCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Events (Venue_ID, Date_Start, Date_End, Time_Start, Time_End, Name, Description, Event_Type, Buy_Tickets_URL) VALUES (@VenID, @DStart, @DEnd, @evTime, @evTime, @Name, @Des, @EvType, @SysUrl);";

                //Other Parameters already inserted here
                string desc = GetDesc(rec.EvName);
                thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", desc);
                thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

None of the other parameters cause a problem but when trying to insert data to the description field I get a database exception saying the field is too small to accept the amount of data. The problem is my program is only trying to insert 3 characters when it throws the error and the Description field is a memo so should be able to hold up to 65000+ characters. When inserting a value manually in the CommandText everything works fine so it must be something to do with the parameter properties.

Comment: There is no problem with inserting three characters, however, parameters have to be listed in the correct order. You show only one parameter in your example, are the others ordered as they appear in your command text?

Comment: Name gets inserted fine into the database, only trying to insert into the description field do I get an exception

Comment: I ran the sample code I posted below, and it worked for me. I cannot see why you cannot insert into description unless one of the parameters has got out of order.

Comment: Just saw the order was a bit off, Had no idea that parameters had to be set in order Thanks!

Comment: Parameter names are irrelevant and not used with MS Access in the scenario you have, you could just as easily use ? as @VenID. All that is important is the order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parameter names are just a guide for you, for example, this runs, note that all parameters have the same name! Note also that the reserved word Name is escaped by square brackets.

```
    thisCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Events (Venue_ID, Date_Start, " +
    "Date_End, [Name], Description, Event_Type, Buy_Tickets_URL) " +
    "VALUES (@VenID, @DStart, @DEnd, @Name, @Des, @EvType, @SysUrl);";


    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", 1);
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", DateTime.Now.Date);
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", DateTime.Now.Date);
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", "abc");
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", "abc");
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", 1);
    thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", "abc");
```

Reserved words

- [Jet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738)
- [ACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875%28v=office.12%29.aspx)

Comment: No problem with Name being reserved word (Names is a reserved word) but pointed out that parameters had to be added in order (in comments on my original question) So best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you need to add braces on Description. `[Description]`

and change your parameters something like:

```
 thisCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Events (Venue_ID, Date_Start, Date_End, Time_Start, Time_End, Name, [Description], Event_Type, Buy_Tickets_URL) VALUES (@VenID, @DStart, @DEnd, @evTime, @evTime, @Name, @Des, @EvType, @SysUrl);

            //Other Parameters already inserted here
            string desc = GetDesc(rec.EvName);
           // thisCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Des", desc);
            thisCommand.Parameters.Add("@Des", OleDbType.VarChar, 6000).Value = desc;
            thisCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Regards

Comment: Description is not a reserved word in [Jet](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/248738) or [ACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb208875(v=office.12).aspx) but Name is. I reckon you should modify that answer.